# SQL aggregate function subquery

Tags: sql, count, subquery, aggregate, rows

What I want to do is count the number of rows returned by a subquery, essentially the following:

```
select pp.prop_id, COUNT((select employee_id from employee e where e.ao1_hours > 0))
  from proposal_piece pp

  group by pp.prop_id
  order by pp.prop_id
```

Here is my error message:

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

Why does this not work? If select is just returning a bunch of `employee_id's` with a filtering criteria why can't I count the number of rows or `employee_id's` that are being returned?

I am looking to count the number of distinct employees that have `ao1_hours > 0`. Grouped by the `prop`.

Here is some structural information about my database, as part of a query.

```
    from proposal_piece pp
    INNER JOIN employee e
    on pp.employee_id = e.employee_id
```

Thanks!

Comment: The result will show every prop_id having the same number of employees.  Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: No, I am looking to count the number of distinct employees that have ao1_hours > 0. Grouped by the prop.

Comment: can you give a datasample of the result you are expecting?

Comment: I just edited my post explaining what I want.

Comment: YOu should join employee and proposal_piece table. How these tables are related?

Comment: Is there any column that references the prop_id in the employees table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
select pp.prop_id, 
      (select COUNT(employee_id) 
       from employee e 
       where e.ao1_hours > 0 and e.employee_id = pp.employee_id) as nb_employees
from proposal_piece pp      
order by pp.prop_id
```

or this

```
select pp.prop_id, count(e.employee_id) as nb_employees  
from proposal_piece pp inner join employee e 
     on pp.employee_id = e.employee_id
where e.ao1_hours > 0
group by pp.prop_id
order by pp.prop_id
```

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk what do you mean?

Comment: I was typing the eaxct same thing