# SQL Server Aggregate Subquery Error for Condition Referencing Parent Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to add an aggregate sub query in select statement for the following code.

```
DECLARE @Date1 Date
DECLARE @Date2 Date

SET @Date1 = '2017-01-01'
SET @Date2 = '2017-03-01'

SELECT  
    p.PracticeName [Practice Name],
    dbo.getFormattedName(l.Userid) [User Name],
    MAX(EventDate) [Last Activity],
    COUNT(*) [Activity Count],
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM UserEvent EVT (NOLOCK) 
     WHERE EVT.EventTypeID = 1 
       AND EVT.UserID = au.userID 
       AND EVT.EventDate >= @Date1 
       AND EVT.EventDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date2)
    GROUP BY 
        au.userID) [Login Count]
FROM    
    dbo.AudLog l (NOLOCK) 
JOIN
    Appuser au (NOLOCK) ON l.UserID = au.UserID
JOIN
    Practice p (NOLOCK) ON au.PracticeID = p.PracticeID
WHERE   
    l.EnvironmentID = 1
    AND EventDate >= @Date1
    AND EventDate <= DATEADD(DAY,1,@Date2)
GROUP BY    
    p.PracticeName,
    dbo.getFormattedName(l.Userid)
ORDER BY    
    p.PracticeName,
    dbo.getFormattedName(l.Userid)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Column 'Appuser.UserID' is invalid in the select list because it is not  contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I don't understand why that error applies to my sub query because I'm not selecting `AppUser.UserID`, I'm just using as a reference for a condition to align the sub query with the parent query. Also, it is indeed in the `GROUP BY` statement within the sub query.

I referenced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312401/sql-aggregate-function-subquery) but based on the explanation I would think my query would be working.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Slight deviation from the topic but an article you really need to read...http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you are referencing is different because there are no aggregate functions in the outer query that require a `GROUP BY`.

When you use a correlated subquery as your have (`EVT.UserID = au.userID`), the outer query column reference, in this case `au.userID`, is now a part of the columns in the outer select (because it is necessary to the subquery).

The simple fix is to add the `au.userID` column to your outer group by.

Comment: I see what you mean. I tried your suggestion at first and was given an error "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference." I replaced the au.UserID in the sub query with evt.UserID and it worked like a charm. Thank you

Comment: @W.Harr Whoops, I overlooked what you had in the subquery grouping.  Good catch and glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you join on a field it is present in the intermediary data set that is part of the join.  Even if it is not in your select list you need to consider it as part of the list.

If you really think it is a non-issue then you can add it to your group by clause and still get the results you desire.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not referencing your sub query.

The following line `dbo.ch_getFormattedProviderName(l.Userid)` in the select clause of your main query is the problem.

You are using the function call `dbo.ch_getFormattedProviderName(l.Userid)` in your select statement but you are grouping by a different function `dbo.getFormattedName(l.Userid)` in your group by clause.

Change the function **`dbo.ch_getFormattedProviderName`** to **`dbo.getFormattedName`** or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for noticing this, I had made a couple minor changes to the query before posting it here. I have made the adjustments you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

It is not answer to your question, but. There are some several things I would like to mention in your query.

- Avoid using scalar functions. Try not use them at all. They are almost no good examples of usage of them. If you wish to encapsulate the logic then just use Table Valued Functions instead. Scalar functions are performance killers especially if you need to filter by them. They will not be indexed and they will execute on every single row.
- Personally I didn't see the situation when such inline sub-queries would outperform normal JOIN inline query. But I saw a lot of opposite situations when the performance was worse. You can always re-write such query with the JOIN (SELECT ...)
- NOLOCKs ... they are not very recommended. If you have locking problems then solving them by taking using index/re-design Technics. It is better to solve the root of the problem rather than doing workarounds.